# Convert JSON representing an array to String[]

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have an external string which represents an array in JSON, like this:

```
["abc", "xyz", "123"]
```

I want to parse this as `String[]` and iterate over it.

---

So far I only have the part of how I want to use it:

```
// value = incoming String
String[] contentUrlList = new String[] { value };
for (int i = 0; i < contentUrlList.length; i++) {
    String contentUri = contentUrlList[i];
}
```

I can also print the length of string array, but it is `1` and not `3`.

```
System.out.println(contentUrlList.length);
```

Comment: Is the incoming an *array of string* or a *string*? What is the *type* of *value*

Comment: Will you please clarify your question

Comment: What data type **exactly** is `value`?

Comment: `String value = "[\"abc\", \"xyz\", \"123\"]"` ?

Comment: What is the format of your incoming string? Is it JSON?

Comment: Incoming value is a string

Comment: @EL323 please show dat string..

Comment: In your case I would recommend using a [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to match you input and iterate over it. 

On the other hand, it looks like a JSON array, so maybe using a off-the-shelf library might be easier.

Comment: @Michael I wouldn't assume the string represents a JSON array until the OP confirms. You probably shouldn't edit that into the title

Comment: Looks like a `JSON` array. Use `Jackson` library to read and parse that data. See http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-collection-array

Comment: @PeterSamokhin The incoming string is like this : `["abc", "xyz"]`

Comment: @pkpnd Whether or not it "is" JSON, it **is** JSON.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name value is of string datatype

Comment: I think I have made a stupid question. I will delete it

Comment: @EL323 it's not a stupid question. It's just being asked in a confusing way

Comment: If you have string which actually contains `"` characters then it probably should be parsed. Many notations are using `["foo", "bar"]` like JSON, so instead of reinventing a wheel use tools which already exist. So pick one of many JSON parsers and use it to parse that text to get String array or other structure like JSONArray which also allows you to iterate over it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the input stays that simple (in particular, no `,` inside the `String`s itself) you can simply remove the first and last character and then split by `,`:

```
String input = "[\"abc\", \"xyz\", \"123\"]"

// Remove the [ and ]
input = input.substring(1, input.length() - 1);
String[] words = input.split(", ");
// Remove the quotation marks
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    words[i] = words[i].substring(1, words[i].length() - 1);
}
```

See [String#substring](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int)) and [String#split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)).

Iterating over the array and printing each element:

```
for (String word : words) {
    System.out.println(word);
}
```

Output:

```
abc
xyz
123
```

---

If it gets more complex I would suggest to use some JSON library. [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) for example:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String[] words = gson.fromJson(input, String[].class);
```

It stays that simple with other libraries too.